# Run script from Host onto PsSession Computer

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following code to run a script from my host computer onto a Vm that I have PSRemoted into (I am successfully remoted into the PSSession). Where am I going wrong?

Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\Script.ps1 -ComputerName PSRemoteComputer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use both a PSSession and the `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` command as you have above.  At that point, you'd be invoking `C:\Script.ps1` on your VM and from your VM (which I assume doesn't exist, since `C:\Script.ps1` exists on your machine).

If you exit your PSSession and run the command as you have typed it above, it should run correctly assuming PSRemoting is correctly enabled, and permissions for the script to run are set.

Keep in mind, objects are handled differently through PSRemoting, so if you are expecting a certain output you may be getting the deserialized version.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need enter-pssession or new-pssession, just use "Invoke-command" and put all commands inside {} of flag "-ScriptBlock {}"

Here I passed remote computer info i.e. ip, username and password with "Invoke-Command" command and passed all command inside {} of flag "-ScriptBlock {}" So It invoked powershell on the remote computer and run all command inside that.

I used below procedure for automation of vm creation on powershell of a remote computer xx.xx.xx.xx using cmd of the local windows system.

1. keep complete code inside a powershell script vm_powershell_script.ps1

**Invoke-Command** -ComputerName xx.xx.xx.xx -Credential (New-object PSCredential -ArgumentList @("username_of_remote_system", ("password_of_remote_system"|ConvertTo-secureString -AsPlainText -Force))) **-ScriptBlock** {New-VM -ComputerName xx.xx.xx.xx -Name centos_c7_VM -MemoryStartupBytes 16GB -BootDevice VHD -VHDPath "C:\ClusterStorage\volume01\demo_vm\virtual Hard disks\demo_vm.vhdx" -Path C:\ClusterStorage\volume01 -Generation 2 -SwitchName "switchname";get-vm -vmname centos_c7_VM ;Set-VMFirmware -VMName centos_c7_VM -EnableSecureBoot Off;start-vm centos_c7_VM;get-vm -vmname centos_c7_VM;Start-Sleep -Seconds 30;Get-VM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters | Select-Object VMName,IPAddresses}

2. run above script from the cmd of the local windows system using below command

**powershell vm_powershell_script.ps1**

So it invoked powershell of remote system and created vm on that remote system.